# Date Picker from Ng2 Bootstrap keep throwing error on unable to read getFullYear()

Tags: angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I was having some problem when trying to disable dates using date picker from ng2-bootstrap. In my app.module.ts, I imported the library as such:

```
import {DatepickerModule} from 'ng2-bootstrap';
@NgModule({
imports: [

    DatepickerModule.forRoot()
],
```

In my html:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 form-group has-feedback" [ngClass]="displayFeedBackCss('testDte')">
        <label for="testDte">TEST DATE<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        <datepicker
            [(ngModel)]="testDte"
            [showWeeks]="true"
            [minDate]="minDate"
            [dateDisabled]="disabledDate"
            [onlyCurrentMonth]=true
        ></datepicker>
    </div>
```

In my ts file:

```
disabledDate:any;
date:Date;

ngOnInit(): void {
this.date = new Date();
this.disabledDate = [
  {dt: this.date.getDate()-1, mode: 'day'},
  {dt: this.date.getDate()-2, mode: 'day'}
];
}
```

However, I kept getting this error message in console:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./e class e - inline template:25:6 caused by: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getFullYear')
e.handleError @ vendor.2b9f55e0bbcf755a8964.js:30
vendor.2b9f55e0bbcf755a8964.js:30 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getFullYear')
```

I even tried to hardcode the dates as '2021-12-16' and '16/12/2021'. However, same error message keep showing still. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Your [`dateDisabled`](https://github.com/formio/ng2-bootstrap/tree/development/components/datepicker) needs to take date value. `{dt: this.date.getDate()-1, mode: 'day'}` is not. `let disabledDate = new Date(); disabledDate.setDate( this.date.getDate()-1)`

Comment: Also https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-bootstrap is long deprecated. You might want to upgrade to `ngx-bootstrap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please note that [`ng2-bootstrap`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-bootstrap) has been deprecated. I suggest moving to [`ngx-bootstrap`](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap)**

```
install ngx-bootstrap --save
```

And refer [The Fabio's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4604645/the-fabio) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70343723/4826457).

The below is for older version.

The [`dateDisabled`](https://github.com/formio/ng2-bootstrap/tree/development/components/datepicker) option takes

> `dateDisabled` (`?Array<{date:Date, mode:string}>`) - array of disabled dates if `mode` is `day`, or years, etc.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.date = new Date();
    let disabledStartDate = new Date();
    disabledStartDate.setDate(this.date.getDate()-1);
    let disabledEndDate = new Date();
    disabledEndDate.setDate(this.date.getDate()-2);
    this.disabledDate = [
        {date:disabledStartDate , mode: 'day'},
        {date:disabledEndDate , mode: 'day'}
    ];
}
```

Comment: Hmm I changed to this solution but I am still getting the same error message Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getFullYear')

Comment: What is `minDate` ? Also `testDte`?

Comment: minDate is the minimum date, the date before the min date will be disabled. if I commented out the dateDisabled, the minDate is working

Comment: @BlackMamba the key is not `dt`. It is `date` in the array

Comment: I am sorry but can check with you do you know what is the correct date format? Is it 'DD/MM/YYYY' or 'YYYY-MM-DD'? For example if I have a list of dates in this format '09/12/2021' how can I set it in this case?

Comment: Date format for which key? they take Date _object_ not string...

Comment: Yes as in because I cant hardcode the dates to be disabled, it will be from my API call and they will return the dates in string format like '09/12/2021', then from there I will set it to the disabledDate list

Comment: You can create a new date object with that.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 Use ISO format

Comment: I tried to change to this then it won't work anymore. let disabledStartDate = new Date('25/12/2021');

Comment: It is taking month first.. Use 'YYYY-MM-DD' or the standard ISO

Comment: COOL THANKS SO MUCH!!! I tried it with let disabledStartDate = new Date('2021-12-25'); and it works already!!

Comment: You are welcome.. I recommend you upgrade to ngx-bootstrap though. It does support angular 2

Answer (score 2):

It seems the issue is that the `datesDisabled` configuration needs to be an array of Dates according to [the docs](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#dates-disabled). And you seem to have used `dateDisabled` (missing 's')

so your template code should be changed with

```
       <datepicker
            [(ngModel)]="testDte"
            [showWeeks]="true"
            [minDate]="minDate"
HERE >>>>   [datesDisabled]="disabledDate"
            [onlyCurrentMonth]=true
        ></datepicker>
```

and your component code also need to be adjusted as per [docs](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#dates-disabled) so what is passed into the `datesDisabled` configuration can be correctly interpreted.

example from the docs:

```
  disabledDates = [
    new Date('2020-02-05'),
    new Date('2020-02-09')
  ];
```

Comment: This is for `ngx-bootstrap`. From the import statement, `import {DatepickerModule} from 'ng2-bootstrap';` OP is clearing using the old version.

Comment: fair enough, My suggestion is to upgrade and follow this answer than... ;-)

Comment: I changed to to datesDisabled but I am getting error message: Can't bind to 'datesDisabled' since it isn't a known property of 'datepicker'.

Comment: @BlackMamba Suraj is right on his comment. this answer is for the current version of ngx-bootstrap. my suggestion is for you to upgrade before using my answer

Comment: @BlackMamba `npm install ngx-bootstrap --save` and check https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap. If you are unable to upgrade for some reason then use my answer.

Comment: @TheFabio My current project is using Angular 2 and I am not able to upgrade it. Is ngc-bootstrap compatible with Angular 2? Or I have to stick to ng2-bootstrap?

Comment: @BlackMamba [Compatibility](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap#compatibility) of ngx-bootstrap